# “Shroom-fuelled” meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, adjectives, compounds

> ... But she has a distinctive postmodern angularity and quirk; Suwichakornpong keeps you off balance with **shroom-fuelled** fantasy and Lynchian departures.

What is the meaning of this compound adjective, shroom-fuelled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Shroom](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shroom) is short for "mushroom" and this word almost always refers to [Psilocybin mushrooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psilocybin_mushroom) that contain a naturally-occurring psychedelic drug which often causes hallucinations and even quasi-spiritual experiences.

**Shroom-fuelled** has the literal meaning of "generated by the effects of consuming psychedelic mushrooms."  However, it is probably being used in a metaphorical sense here, meaning, "so creative and mind-bending, that it's as if you (or the film director) were consuming psychedelic mushrooms."

A common synonym would be [trippy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/trippy), which means "resembling the effect produced by a hallucinogenic drug," and comes from the phrase "drug trip."